# Half-orc subraces?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, half-orc

I am interested in finding alternative subraces for half-orcs, especially those with less-terrible ability scores. I am aware of the *Unearthed Arcana* environmental variants (aquatic, arctic, desert, and jungle half-orcs) and elemental variants (water half-orc), and I’m aware of the frostblood half-orcs from *Dragon Magic*, but these are literally the only examples I can find.<sup>1</sup>

It must “be” a half-orc (have “half-orc” in the race name), or qualify as one for requirements. Full-blooded orcs, sadly, can’t apply (looking to use half-orc paragon). Sources can include any Wizards of the Coast-published 3.5e material, or *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazine content. LA +0 vastly preferred, but since I’m grasping at straws here, I’ll happily take a look at stuff with a higher LA or even unplayable stuff, so long as it is some variant half-orc and not just a template applied to half-orcs.

1. <sub>For the record, the sharakim from *Races of Destiny* are **not** an answer here. Despite their introduction being “Humans assume all orcs are the same [...] one group in particular stands apart from all others,” ***sharakim aren’t orcs***, half- or otherwise. They’re “tainted humans;” they have the human subtype, and not the orc subtype. Orcs were already an offensive caricature, but honestly the way this write-up dangles even a little bit of redemption for the race and then re-assigns it back to humanity is beyond the pale. I hope whoever wrote this description has learned better since and is ashamed of it.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that sharakim are the only potential half-orcs from _Races of Destiny_? That book mentions half-orcs an awful lot.

Comment: @J.Mini I looked, couldn’t find any! I thought so too, but there didn’t seem to be anything. Happy to be proven wrong, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Scablands Half-Orc

I hunted around every race list that I could find, and, aside from Chet Erez's outdated work, [this one](https://ihititwithmyaxe.tumblr.com/post/9678117696/every-playable-race-in-35-dd-without-a-level/amp) was the only one that did the job. As far as I can tell, your only omission is the Scablands Half-Orc from page 43 of *Sandstorm*. Everything else is either homebrew, 3rd party, or Pathfinder.

Frankly, the subrace isn't notable for anything. Its only changes from the base half-orc are:

- Low-light vision rather than darkvision
- Some protection against thirst
- Heat Endurance as a bonus feat

I think that you've got everything else. Neither my own regex work nor [Chet Erez's old index](https://web.archive.org/web/20180922083446/http://chet.kindredcircle.org/pdf/DnD3.5Index-Races.pdf) had any more to say.

Comment: Insanity, but thank you so much for your hunting and backing up my “nothing.” I’m gonna just go ahead and accept—if someone comes up with more, then great, but I doubt anyone will.

Comment: @KRyan I've finished my final checks. Unless there's something hidden in the books that have already been mentioned, I'm confident that you've got everything.

Comment: [This index](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1281.0) likewise doesn't go any further than what's already listed, but it may be useful in providing additional confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to admit Kingdoms of Kalamar material, the **Dangerous Denizens** book has the Tel-amhothlan, an half-orc/half elf hybrid: no listed LA and explicitly has  the orc-blood trait.

Comment: Considering how we have found a grand total of eight sub-races of half-orc ’til now, yeah, I’m willing to look anywhere, +1. An elf/orc hybrid would be super-relevant to my interests; too bad it isn’t playable.